# Возможные варианты преобразования PDF в картинки

Tags: c#, pdf

Использую библиотеку `Cyotek.GhostScript.PdfConversion`, но к сожалению он не все PDF кушает. Использую COM объект Acrobat Pro, но устанавливать Pro версию на все ПК дело затратное (лицензии стоят не дешево). PDFSharp, iTextSharp не позволяют конвертировать (или у меня не получается). Вопрос: Какие еще есть библиотеки разбора PDF?

Comment: Попробуй библиотеку [ImageMagick](http://git.imagemagick.org/repos/ImageMagick).

Comment: Блин... Не совсем .net либа. dll ка внутри установщика. А либы .net либо адаптированные под .net существуют?

Comment: Вот ещё нашел [ABCpdf .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ABCpdf/9.1.1.6), звучит красиво, аж самому захотелось попробовать:D [Мини инструктаж](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/447b4310-2d9f-4307-b648-775f6d091ab1/how-to-convert-pdf-to-tiff-through-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: А есть пример PDF-ки, которую он не кушает?

Comment: Есть. К сожалению корпоративный фейрволл не пропускает файлы.

Comment: Ура! Понял в чем проблема!

Comment: `-q -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile=tmpF85B.tmp -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -dUseCIEColor -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dGridFitTT=2 -r300 -dUseCropBox=true "ОТМ-Х-9м2015г- ПРИВ.pdf"` в имени файла не должно быть пробелов! Во я затупил!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что автор сам понял в чем была проблема - и она оказалась никак не связана с вопросом :)